# Set max height and make scrollable text field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have implemented MUI auto complete component with a textfield to display all selected items. However the height of the text field increases and I would like to set a max height to it. I tried to pass maxRows prop to textfield but it has no effect. Please find my code and screenshot of the issue bellow.

```
// Component for select input which can be filtered through text input
export default function FormSearchInput( props ) {
  const classes = FormStyle();
  const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
  const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;
  return (
    <Grid item xs = {props.xs} className = {classes.formItem}>
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      id = "checkboxes-tags-demo"
      options = {props.options}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel = {( option ) => option}
      defaultValue = {props.selectedOptions}
      renderOption = {( option, {selected} ) => (
      <React.Fragment>
      <Checkbox
        icon = {icon}
        checkedIcon = {checkedIcon}
        style = {{ marginRight: 8 }}
        checked = {selected}
        onChange = {props.onChange( option, selected )}
      />
        {option}
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
    renderInput = {( params ) => {
      return <TextField {...params} multiline rowsMax = {2} variant = "outlined" label = {props.label}/>
    }}
    />
  </Grid>
  )
}
```

Issue (textfield should only be 2 rows height):
[image: textfield rowsmax not applying]

Comment: Can you show your imports?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-lbfb6?file=/demo.js